# Replace special characters in python

Tags: python, string

I have some text coming from the web as such:

Â£6.49

Obviously I would like this to be displayed as:

£6.49

I have tried the following so far:

```
s = url['title']
s = s.encode('utf8')
s = s.replace(u'Â','')
```

And a few variants on this (after finding it on this very same forum)

But still no luck as I keep getting:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   100: ordinal not in range(128)

Could anyone help me getting this right?

UPDATE:

Adding the repr examples and content type

```
u'Star Trek XI &#xA3;3.99'
u'Oscar Winners Best Pictures Box Set \xc2\xa36.49'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the text from the web coming in such a bad form?

Comment: Please post the `repr(...)` of the string from the web. Then we'll know for sure what we are dealing with.

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(repr(url['title']))`?

Comment: And why it is bad in XML? Are you trying to work around inconsistent input? Yep, and repr(url['title']) would probably help.

Comment: It might also help to post the `Content-Type` header: `response=urllib2.urlopen(url);content_type=response.headers.getheader('Content-Type')`

Comment: Updated with some reppr examples I get back

Comment: Btw, shouldn't you use 'decode' instead of encode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If, `s=url['title']` makes `s` equal to this:

```
In [48]: s=u'Oscar Winners Best Pictures Box Set \xc2\xa36.49'
```

Then the problem is

1. in the code that defines `url`,
2. or else the content from the web is
   mal-formed.

If Case 1, we'd need to see the code that defines `url`.

If Case 2, a quick-and-dirty workaround would be to encode the unicode object `s` with the `raw-unicode-escape` codec:

```
In [49]: print(s)
Oscar Winners Best Pictures Box Set Â£6.49

In [50]: print(s.encode('raw-unicode-escape'))
Oscar Winners Best Pictures Box Set £6.49
```

See also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4663250/190597).

---

Regarding titles like `s=u'Star Trek XI &#xA3;3.99'`: Again, it would be nice fix the problem before it gets to this stage -- perhaps by looking at how `url` is defined. But assuming the content from the web is mal-formed, a workaround would be:

```
In [86]: import re

In [87]: print(re.sub(r'&#x([a-fA-F\d]+);',lambda m: unichr(int(m.group(1),base=16)),s))
Star Trek XI £3.99
```

---

A little bit of explanation:

Note that

```
In [51]: x=u'£'
In [53]: x.encode('utf-8')
Out[53]: '\xc2\xa3'
```

So the unicode object `u'£'`, encoded with the `utf-8` codec, becomes the string object `'\xc2\xa3'`.

Somehow, `url['title']` is getting defined to be the *unicode* object
`u'\xc2\xa3'`. (The `u` makes a big difference!)

Thus we have `u'\xc2\xa3'` when we desire `'\xc2\xa3'`. 
Encoding the unicode object `u'\xc2\xa3'` with the `raw-unicode-escape` codec transforms it to `'\xc2\xa3'`.

Comment: Hi, we're almost there, your code did the trick for the second string, but the first one still displays wrong (Star Trek XI &#xA3;3.99)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: you have your objects already in unicode. Seems to me there is no reason to actually use enocde/decode at all.

```
>>> print u'Oscar Winners Best Pictures Box Set \xc2\xa36.49'.replace(u'Â','')
Oscar Winners Best Pictures Box Set £6.49
```

However it seems to me that something is wrong there. The unicode objects are actually not unicode; see:

```
>>> print 'Oscar Winners Best Pictures Box Set \xc2\xa36.49'.decode('utf8')
Oscar Winners Best Pictures Box Set £6.49
```

The repr() you posted should not be unicode object. That's why I was asking where are you getting the data, there is something wrong.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 100-101: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You should post repr() of the string that this fails for and the particular line (i.e. does it fail on the decode?).