# Python: special characters giving me problems (from PDFminer)

Tags: python

I used pdf2text from PDFminer to reduce a PDF to text. Unfortunately it contains special characters. Let me show output from my console

```
>>>a=pdf_to_text("ap.pdf")
```

heres a sample of it, a little truncated

```
>>>a[5000:5500]
'f one architect. Decades ...... but to re\xef\xac\x82ect\none set of design ideas, than to have one that contains many\ngood but independent and uncoordinated ideas.\n1 Joshua Bloch, \xe2\x80\x9cHow to Design a Good API and Why It Matters\xe2\x80\x9d, G......=-3733'
```

I understood that I must encode it

```
>>>a[5000:5500].encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 237: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I searched around a bit and tried them, notably [Replace special characters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705793/replace-special-characters-in-python) . The input comes from PDFminer, so its tough (AFAIK) to control that. What is the way to make proper **plaintext** from this output?

What am I doing wrong?

**--A quick fix: change PDFminer's codec to ascii- but it's not a lasting solution--**

**--Abandoned the quick fix for the answer- changing the codec removes information --**

**--A relavent topic as mentioned by Maxim http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251 --**

Comment: Thanks for this question! Im beginner in Python could you maybe post a demo code how to use Pdfminer so that this errors dont appaer? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem often occurs when non-ASCII text is stored in `str` objects. What you are trying to do is to encode in `utf-8` a string already encoded in some encoding (because it contains characters with codes above `0x7f`).

To encode such a string in `utf-8` it has to be first decoded. Assuming that the original text encoding is `cp1251` (replace it with your actual encoding), something like the following would do the trick:

```
u = s.decode('cp1251')  # decode from cp1251 byte (str) string to unicode string
s = u.encode('utf-8')   # re-encode unicode string to  utf-8 byte (str) string
```

Basically, the above snippet does what `iconv --from-code=CP1251 --to-code=UTF-8` command does, i.e. it converts the string from one encoding to another.

Some useful links:

- [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)
- [Developing Unicode-aware Applications in Python](http://downloads.egenix.com/python/LSM2005-Developing-Unicode-aware-applications-in-Python.pdf)

Comment: Yes, this works close to flawlessly! I got a few artifacts like "...Ð²Ð‚ÑšDelivering Custo.." but it was a PDF made by amateurs for maximum glitz. Cleaner PDFs are cleanly parsed.

Comment: Nice one, you need to know your input encoding though.

Comment: I'd definitely write it as `a.decode('cp1250').encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @JanHudec I spelled it out in two lines to be able to put comments, i.e. for the clarity of exposition only.

Comment: @aitchnyu What IS the PDFMiner encoding - cp1250?